# Almost a genius riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My prefix is a means of division,
My infix is almost at the kirk,
My suffix is just by provision,
My whole is the result of hard work.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My whole is the result of hard work.

> **perspiration** - sweat from working hard

My prefix is a means of division,

> per - this splits a quantity, as in two sweets per person

My infix is almost at the kirk,

> spir - almost a spire which is found on top of a church

My suffix is just by provision,

> ration - portion out say food so as to last the duration

Title: Almost a genius riddle

> Thomas Edison said 'Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.'

Comment: Edison? I thought it was Einstein. Anyway +1, you got it.